# How to cast lambda parameter to char in the ifPresentOrElse() method

Tags: java, for-loop, lambda, java-stream, stack

How do I fix this code block (in `ifPresentOrElse()`)?

I'm stuck here with:

```
Inconvertible types; cannot cast '<lambda parameter>' to 'char'
```

Please advise how to get this compiled and running.

```
public static boolean isBracketsInOrder1(String bracket) {
    
    Stack<Character> charStack = new Stack<>();
    static Map<Character, Character> leftToRightBracketsMap = 
                                       Map.of('{', '}', '[', ']', '(', ')');
    bracket.chars()
        .filter(i -> leftToRightBracketsMap.containsKey((char) i))
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresentOrElse((i) -> charStack.push((char) i),
            (i) -> {
                // code does not COMPILE at equals((char) i)
                return leftToRightBracketsMap.get(charStack.pop()).equals((char) i);
            });
    return true;
}
```

And this is the working code using `for` loop representing what I'm trying to implement above using streams above.

```
public static boolean isBracketsInOrder(String bracket) {
    Stack<Character> charStack = new Stack<>();
    static Map<Character, Character> leftToRightBracketsMap = 
                                       Map.of('{', '}', '[', ']', '(', ')');
    boolean matchFound = true;
    for (char c : bracket.toCharArray()) {
        if (leftToRightBracketsMap.containsKey(c)) charStack.push(c);
        else {
            char leftBrack = charStack.pop();
            char correctBrack = leftToRightBracketsMap.get(leftBrack);
            if (c != correctBrack) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the definition of the `leftToRightBracketsMap`? mainly It's type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've introduced the code for a very basic algorithmic question - *validate a string of brackets*.

There are many mistakes in your code:

- A *stream* doesn't act precisely like a *loop*, when it hits the *terminal operation* (which is `findFirst()` in your code), it's done. Code inside `ifPresentOrElse()` would **not** be executed multiple times (*you probably expected the opposite*). It would be invoked only once on an optional result returned by the `findFirst()`.
- As its second argument [`ifPresentOrElse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresentOrElse(java.util.function.Consumer,java.lang.Runnable)) expects an instance of the `Runnable` interface. Method `run()` neither expects any arguments, no returns a value. Therefore, this attempt to define a `Runnable` is incorrect: `(i) -> { return something; }`.
- Any *lambda expressions* should to conform to a particular *functional interface* ([*see*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)). It can't appear out of nowhere.
- Class `Stack` is legacy, it's still in the JDK for backward compatibility reasons. Implementations of the `Deque` interface should be used instead.
- You are not checking whether the stack is empty, which can cause an `EmptyStackException`. If you would replace the `Stack` with `ArrayDeque` the problem will remain, method `pop()` will throw `NoSuchElementException`. You need to make sure that stack is not empty.
- Returning `true` in the imperative solution is not correct. Instead, you need to return `charStack.isEmpty()`, because if there are some elements in the stack - sequence is not valid, there are brackets that haven't been closed.

Implementing this problem using streams requires far more efforts than a solution using a plain loop.

According to the documentation, the only place where mutation can occur in a stream is inside the *collector*. As a general rule, all functions used in a stream pipeline should [*not operate via side effects and accumulate the stated outside the stream*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness) (*apart from some edge cases, see the link*). Only collector's *mutable container* should maintain a state.

We can contract such a collector using `Collecor.of()` method:

```
public static boolean isValidBracketSequence(String brackets) {
    return brackets.chars()
        .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
        .collect(getBracketCollector());
}

public static Collector<Character, ?, Boolean> getBracketCollector() {
    
    return Collector.of(
        BracketContainer::new,
        BracketContainer::add,
        (left, right) -> { throw new AssertionError("should not be executed in parallel"); },
        bracketContainer -> bracketContainer.isValid() && bracketContainer.isEmpty()
    );
}
```

That's how a *mutable container* might look like:

```
class BracketContainer {
    public static final Map<Character, Character> leftToRightBracketsMap =
        Map.of('(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}');
    
    private Deque<Character> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
    private boolean isValid = true;
    
    public void add(Character next) {
        if (!isValid) return;
        
        if (leftToRightBracketsMap.containsKey(next)) {
            stack.push(next);
        } else {
            compare(next);
        }
    }
    
    public void compare(Character next) {
        
        this.isValid = !isEmpty() && leftToRightBracketsMap.get(stack.pop()).equals(next);
    }
    
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return stack.isEmpty();
    }
    
    public boolean isValid() {
        return isValid;
    }
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("(([])) -> " + isValidBracketSequence("(([]))")); // true
    System.out.println("(([]]) -> " + isValidBracketSequence("(([]])")); // false
    System.out.println("(([})) -> " + isValidBracketSequence("(([}))")); // false
    System.out.println("({[])) -> " + isValidBracketSequence("({[]))")); // false
    System.out.println("({[]}) -> " + isValidBracketSequence("({[]})")); // true
}
```

*Output:*

```
(([])) -> true
(([]]) -> false
(([})) -> false
({[])) -> false
({[]}) -> true
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/s9l)

Comment: How is the `distinct()` stream operation stateless?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn `distintct()`, `sorted()`, `takeWhile()`, etc. are stateful. I didn't frame the phrase properly. Changed this statement, I hope now it's clear what I intended to convey.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko - thanks ! that was very informative .